# Retrieving Sessions in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there anyway to retrieve the previous session in SQLite? The databases I created got deleted once I restart the session.

Comment: Are you talking about in-memory databases or on-disk databases? If you have a database in a file on disk then you should be able to re-open the same database later and the data still be present. If you're not sure then it would be helpful to see the code you're using to open the database, create the schema, and run queries.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I think in-memory databases. When I enter `.tables` and `.schema`, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

In order to persist a database for later use you must have sqlite create a file on disk for the database. The most common way to do this is to give a database name when you launch sqlite:

```
sqlite3 some_file.db
```

If the file doesn't exist it will be created. If it does already exist, then SQLite will open it.

Another less common approach is to launch `sqlite3` with no parameters and then use [the `ATTACH` statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to connect a database file. This allows you to open multiple database files in the same session.